# How to test jQuery template content on codeception

Tags: testing, phantomjs, codeception

anyone knows how to test content generated by jQuery template?
I'm using codeception to build tests for my web application.
The problem is that the browser used by codeception cannot render this content, and, with that, i cannot test this html content. 
PhpBrowser was the first "browser" used it's not possible test with it.
I thought that with phantomjs this problem could be solved but i have the same problem.

Any idea?

Comment: You probably need to wait in the script.

Comment: I suggest you use the WebDriver with selenium & Firefox for testing the client side code http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver, then switching to phantomjs tests

Comment: On important thing that i didn't said is that i'm using vagrant.

Comment: @321zeno my tests are running on my vagrant machine. Is it possible use selenium & firefox ?

Comment: I think it depends on the OS setup inside you Vagrant box but I guess it's a "windowless" environment so you wouldn't be able to run Firefox. I would probably set up Codeception to run on my desktop machine via Selenium + Firefox first, just to make sure my tests are properly written because it's quite easy to mess up selectors and interaction instructions in Codeception. Testing the test.

Comment: Sure, that's the point. I'm running my tests on ubuntu (without graphic interface) because it's like a simulation of integration server (where tests should run). Running tests on local machine will not help i think.

Comment: Haven't try it yet, but whats about a selenium docker container including firefox/chrome binaries (xvfb) and phantomjs? If you already run Vagrant, it's not that big deal, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the browser used by codeception cannot render this
>   content..

Codeception's WebDriver module can run a full Firefox instance, and can run any jQuery. You should be able to run Selenium on a Vagrant box. Use VVV.